# NSMutableString returning (null)

Tags: objective-c

What's wrong with this? The NSMutableString returns `(null)`.

#### .h:

```
NSMutableString *aMutableString;
...
@property (assign) NSMutableString *aMutableString;
```

#### .m:

```
@synthesize aMutableString;

- (void)aMethod {
    [self setAMutableString:[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"message: "]];
    if (someCondition) {
        [[self aMutableString] appendString:@"woohoo"];
    }
}

- (void)anotherMethod {
    NSLog(@"%@", [self aMutableString]);
    [[self aMutableString] release];
}
```

Comment: Are you invoking `anotherMethod` before you invoke `aMethod`?

Comment: I don't know... anotherMethod is a -windowDidLoad.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Thanks! I didn't show that in the simplified example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code has a couple of problems. First, you should define your `aMutableString` `@property` as `retain`, not `assign`. `assign` is generally for primitive, non-object types, like `int`s, etc., and for some special cases of objects. You appear to want to take ownership of `aMutableString` in such a way that it persists after the event loop returns. In your posted code, you end up accomplishing that because of how you incorrectly set the `aMutableString` in the following line:

```
[self setAMutableString:[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"message: "]];
```

By creating an NSMutableString with alloc/init, you're creating a potential memory leak situation, though in your situation, it actually makes up for your defining the property as `assign` rather than retain.

Your second `-anotherMethod` is also potentially dangerous in that:
1) it releases an instance variable you defined as `assign`
2) after releasing it, it doesn't set it to `nil`. If you try to access that instance variable elsewhere in that class at a later point in time, you will likely get a crash because the pointer is no longer valid, if the instance variable has been dealloced.

So, the code should most likely look something like this:

.h

```
NSMutableString *aMutableString;
...
@property (retain) NSMutableString *aMutableString;
```

.m:

```
@synthesize aMutableString;

- (void)dealloc {
   [aMutableString release];
   [super dealloc];
}

- (void)aMethod {
    [self setAMutableString:[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"message: "]];
    if (someCondition) {
        [aMutableString appendString:@"woohoo"];
    }
}

- (void)anotherMethod {
    NSLog(@"%@", aMutableString);
    // the following is potentially unsafe!
    // [[self aMutableString] release];
    // it should be one of the following:
    [aMutableString release]; aMutableString = nil;
    // or
    // [self setAMutableString:nil];
}
```

That said, without more information, it's a little hard to say what the problem is. I assume you mean the `NSLog()` call is printing `(null)`? If so, that means that `aMutableString` is still `nil`. Are you calling `-aMethod` before calling `-anotherMethod`?

If you want to make sure that `aMutableString` is initialized to an empty string, you could override `-init`:

```
- (id)init {
  if ((self = [super init])) {
      aMutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: yeah, that was it - I was calling anotherMethod before aMethod.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `@synthesize aMutableString;` in your .m file

Comment: I actually did that but forgot to add it to the example.